# CSS tooltip on image

Tags: css, html, image, tooltip

I am beginer in creating of webpages and i would be grateful for an easy simple example of CSS tooltip on image with Html5 standard. I know there are some examples but they are kinda hard for me.

Comment: `I know there are some examples but they are kinda hard for me.`  So why would it be any easier here?

Comment: I hope there are some people that have some experiance with teaching. I need an example without styles. Just basic simple CSS tooltip on image..

Comment: check this css tooltip lists http://www.designerslib.com/tag/css-tooltip/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is probably the simplest tooltip that takes advantage of the native title attribute of an element:

```html
<style>
    p[title]:hover:after {
        content: attr(title);
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;  
    }
</style>

<p title="I am a tooltip!">Hover over me</p>
```